# Use string value as a variable? C#

Tags: c#, string, variables

I just want to know if it is possible:

```
int num1;
string aux = num1;

aux(value) = 100;

Console.WriteLine(num1);

// Output: 100
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? sounds like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (obviously) but it's also really hard to understand what you're after. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I think they want to hold the name of a variable as a string, and then evaluate the value of that variable at runtime.  However, their code sample doesn't seem to illustrate that at all.

Comment: @MikeChristensen The code sample does seem to illustrate it.  He has a string value in which the value of that string is the name of a local variable, he wants to perform some operation on the string (rather than `num1`) and have it change the local variable's value, as demonstrated by the expected output.

Comment: I don't see any strings being set to the name of any variables.  Maybe if they put `string aux = "num1";` it would have been more clear.  With that said, I made the same assumption as you did because there's not really any other good interpretations.  This appears to be another unclear question where the author dumps some meaningless code and then never comes back again.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a variable variable like in PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to evaluate the value of a local variable given that variable's identifier as a string.

Comment: This is a valid answer, not really sure why it has been downvoted.

Comment: @Habib: probably because there's no way to know if this is what the OP is actually asking. There are many more possible answers along those lines.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The title makes it pretty clear, and the code sample does very much re-enforce that as an example.  He wants to use a string value as a variable.  He can't do that.  The question without the title is indeed somewhat more confusing.  What other interpretations are you seeing?

Comment: I avoid speculating out loud on what the OP could mean since I find it rarely helps -- so I'll pass. You think it's clear and provided an answer accordingly, that's fine. I was just answering @Habib's question. (And no, I didn't downvote, just in case that matters to anyone. :-))

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't suspect you downvoted at all.  I'm genuinely curious what other interpretations you see in the question.  I honestly can't see anything else that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. In your request you are trying to assign an integer to a string. C# will now allow this. Instead of

```
        int num1;
        string aux = num1;
```

You would write

```
        int num1;
        string aux = num1.ToString();
```

Your next statement doesn't make much sense as you are using `aux()` as a method instead of `aux` as a string or integer. If you want your output to be `num1` then make `value` equal your integer and get rid of your `aux`.

```
        int num1;
        //string aux = num1.ToString();
        value = 100;

        num1 = value;

        Console.WriteLine(num1);
```

And to follow up this is how you might write `aux()` as a method

```
    private void aux(int value)
    {
        int num1;
        //string aux = num1.ToString();
        value = 100;

        num1 = value;

        Console.WriteLine(num1);
    }
```

I think in plain English it says 'I want a formula that turns `aux` into an integer with the value of 100 that is going to be written to a book with a page named `num1`'

Are there any pro's that can confirm this for me? I'm I thinking through this correctly?

Comment: As per the title, he's trying to access a variable given a string with that variable's name.  This isn't doing that, this is just setting the variable directly at compile time.  He's not just asking how to set the value of a variable.

Comment: @Servy Just trying to be helpful :-D Trying to give back some of what I've gotten here. Thanks for the input though :-D